# Issue with Timer Using React Lifecycle Methods

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working on updating a react native app that someone else worked on. I am noticing some strange behavior in a timer that one of the components uses, and I'm wondering if it has to do with the way `setState()` is being used in the component:

```
  async _startTimer() {
    if (this.timer) clearInterval(this.timer);

    let stateUpdate = {
      stopTime: null,
    };

    const newStartTime = moment(Date.serverTime() || Date.now());
    if (!this.state.startTime) {
      stateUpdate.startTime = newStartTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
      stateUpdate.startDuration = newStartTime.format('HH:mm');
    }

    this.setState(stateUpdate, () => {
      this.timer = setInterval(async () => {
        const duration = this._getDuration();
        this.setState({
          duration: duration.long,
          shortDuration: duration.short,
          stopDuration: duration.stopTime.format('HH:mm'),
        });
      }, 1000);

      if (this.props.onChange) this.props.onChange(this.state);
    });
  }
```

This is designed to update the component state every 1 second, so that the user sees a timer ticking along, one second at a time. However, I am noticing that even though `clearInterval` is called within `componentWillUnmount()`, I can see `this.state.duration` is still ticking along, updating every 1000ms/1sec, even after the user has navigated away from the component.

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('VisitTimer() component is unmounting...');
    if (this.timer) clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
```

By the way, `_getDuration()` looks like this:

```
  _getDuration() {
    let msDuration =
      (this.state.stopTime
        ? moment(this.state.stopTime).valueOf()
        : moment(Date.serverTime() - this.state.stopTimeOffset).valueOf()) -
      (this.state.startTime ? moment(this.state.startTime).valueOf() : moment(Date.serverTime()).valueOf());

    // detect maximum duration in millisecondsr
    if (this.props.maxDuration && this.state.stopTime === null && msDuration >= this.props.maxDuration) {
      msDuration = this.props.maxDuration;

      this.setState(
        {
          stopTimeOffset:
            moment(Date.serverTime()).valueOf() - (moment(this.state.startTime).valueOf() + this.props.maxDuration),
          maxDurationReached: true,
        },
        () => {
          this._stopTimer();
          if (this.props.onMaxDurationReached) this.props.onMaxDurationReached();
        }
      );
    }

    if (msDuration < 0) msDuration = 0;
    const diff = moment.utc(msDuration);

    let long = diff.format('HH:mm:ss');
    let short = diff.format('HH:mm');

    return {
      long: long,
      short: short,
      stopTime: moment(moment(this.state.startTime).valueOf() + msDuration),
    };
  }
```

And the block of the component that calls this `<VisitTimer>` looks like this:

```
  <VisitTimer
    started={this.props?.visit?.dates?.started?.value}
    stopped={this.props?.visit?.dates?.completed?.value}
    durationOverride={this.props?.visit?.duration?.total?.value}
    maxDuration={maxVisitTime(this.props?.visit?.type?.value)}
    visit={this.props?.visit}
    discipline={this.props?.patient?.discipline}
    therapistDisciplines={this.props?.therapistDisciplines}
    isChangeRequest={this.state.isChangeRequest}
    disabled={this.state.isCheckoutOutsideHomeGeoFence}
    isBlankLogSheet={this.state.isBlankLogSheet}
    isTest={this.props?.patient?.isTest}
    ref={(ref) => (this.visitTimer = ref)}
    onMaxDurationReached={() => {
      Alert.alert(
        'Maximum Duration Reached',
        `Please enter an accurate manual stop time in the field provided.`,
        [
          {
            text: 'OK',
            onPress: () => {},
            style: 'cancel',
          },
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
      );
      this.setState({ showManualStopTime: true });
    }}
    stopTimeOffset={this.props.visit?.duration?.stopOffset?.value}
    editable={statusCodeToEditableLevel(this.props.visit?.status?.value) === 2}
    onError={(error) => {
      reportError(error, 'components/VisitTimer');
    }}
    onChange={this._onVisitTimerChange}
  />
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

Update the component state will create a new instance of the component object with updated data.

`setTimeout` is an asynchronous function, even if the component has been re-created, setTimeout is still running in the background.

For the next component rerender, the component will re-assign a new instance of setTimeout to `this.timer` property again.

When the component unmounts, the app will release the latest `setTimeout` instance but the previous instances are still running in the background which should cause a memory leak.

**Solution**

React offers a way to directly reference a variable on the memory level with Refs via `React.createRef`  or `React.useRef`.

Ref value will always persist its value for every component rerender. Let's assign setTimeout to React Ref.

```js
const timer = React.createRef(null)

  async _startTimer() {
    if (timer.current) clearInterval(timer.current);

    let stateUpdate = {
      stopTime: null,
    };

    const newStartTime = moment(Date.serverTime() || Date.now());
    if (!this.state.startTime) {
      stateUpdate.startTime = newStartTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
      stateUpdate.startDuration = newStartTime.format('HH:mm');
    }

    this.setState(stateUpdate, () => {
      timer.current = setInterval(async () => {
        const duration = this._getDuration();
        this.setState({
          duration: duration.long,
          shortDuration: duration.short,
          stopDuration: duration.stopTime.format('HH:mm'),
        });
      }, 1000);

      if (this.props.onChange) this.props.onChange(this.state);
    });
  }



componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('VisitTimer() component is unmounting...');
    if (timer.current) clearInterval(timer.current);
    
  }
```